# What makes a good sample image for ISO comparison?

Tags: image-quality, iso, iso-noise, picture-samples

To be more specific [this image](http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Olympus-PEN-E-PL3-ISO-200.jpg) is always used by [Digital Photography School](http://www.digital-photography-school.com) for ISO comparison. What are those features that make this image suitable for ISO comparison.

Comment: Gluten free and organic? ewww ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ISO comparisons you need to have a bit of everything, shadow, good range of mid tones, and some highlights plus a range of colours. This shot has all of that, which is why it's an ideal shot to analyse how well a camera deals with various ISO settings. Basically for any performance analysis in a single shot there needs to be as wide a range of colour, tone and detail as possible to judge how a camera deals with each of these factors so thats what makes images such as this very good for the job.